# How can I have AutoHotKey convert java output to text format?

Tags: java, automation

Is there a way to have AutoHotKey type the output of my .java file? Can anyone offer insight? For instance, if my hat.txt file has:

paper
rock
scissors

how can I type an AHK keystroke (Ctrl + g) and have it type "scissors" or whatever is the output from my .java file?

So far I can map AHK script to a key (Ctrl + g). Then a DOS window appears and closes. The .java file I wrote has (it compiles in JGrasp with no errors. It requires a simple hat.txt notepad file to process.):

```
    /* Created by John Thrush 7/20/16
   MagicHat.java scans a simple Hat.txt file line by line
   and randomly selects one line to display in an applet.
    Put anything you like into the hat and pull out a rabbit.
*/

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Font;
public class MagicHat
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
    {
      try
       {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hat.txt"));
         String line = reader.readLine();
         List<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();

           while (line != null) 
        {
            listOfLines.add(line.replace("\t", "   "));
            line = reader.readLine();
         }
         Random r = new Random();
         String randomLine = listOfLines.get(r.nextInt(listOfLines.size()));

         JLabel label = new JLabel(randomLine);
         label.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 28));
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"Magic Hat",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
         System.out.println(randomLine);
        // listOfLines.remove(randomLine); //remove this line if you don't want to randomly choose items more than once
      }
       catch (IOException e)
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage()+" for hat.txt","File Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

My AHK testfile has (this is my best guess w/o knowing AHK syntax very well):

;JavaTest

^g::
Run,java -cp MagicHat.class,C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\John Thrush\Java JFT\CompleteCode

Comment: `System.out.println()` writes to the console window (the *DOS* window that isn't a *DOS* window, because *DOS* died years ago). You're asking if there's a way to redirect that console output to AHK? If so, [edit] your question and phrase it more clearly. If not, then [edit] your question and explain more clearly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you using java? `type myfile.txt`

Comment: "You're asking if there's a way to redirect that console output to AHK? " -Yes, that's what I would like to accomplish. AHK is a convenient tool that I'm learning to use. If there is a way to have AHK read lines from a .txt file and randomly type one line out without java, that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your console output from Java's `System.out.println()` to be stored to a textfile, you can do it by just using:

```
C:\> java myProgram > output.txt
```

All the output that is supposed to be displayed on the console will be saved into the text file stated in the command.

Since you are already opening a command prompt to run your java program, just add the command for output redirection to a text file.

Comment: agreed this should not require autohot keys to do.  You could also set up a java logger to log to a file separately

Comment: Yes, or he could just create a batch file to do that.